# Why am I able to input an arbitrarily large amount of semicolons after the return statement of a function?

Tags: c++

I find that in a function return statement I am able to do this.

```
int f() {
    return 1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; // ...;;;
}
```

I can add as many semicolons as I want and the above doesn't result in any compiler or runtime errors. This surprised me coming from a strict language like C++. Can someone explain why I am able to do this? I'm *unable*, however, to do this in any other context.

```
int x = 1;;;; // error
```

So can someone tell me why I am able to do something like this?

Comment: What error do you get from that `int x = 0;;;;` line?  It's totally valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from K&R, expression statement has product `expression-statement: expression;`.

> If the expression is missing, the construction is called a null statement;
>       it is often used to supply an empty body to an iteration statement to place
>       a label.

It is a valid language construct, so no complains from your compiler.

Comment: If anyone's interested, C++11 has it in §6.3.

Answer (score 1):

They're just empty statements.

```
return 1;
; //do nothing
; //do nothing
//etc
```

I'll bet the difference you're seeing is that `int x = 0;;;;;` is in the global scope, so -pedantic gets it. It's like having an extra semicolon after a function definition. Move `int x = 0;;;;` into a function and it won't complain.